# recyclerview-selection how to listen event onSelectionEnter and event onSelectionExit

Tags: java, android

I use following to use recyclerview-selection:

```
selectionTracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>("lazy-load-img-list-selection", this.recyclerView, new KeyProvider(1), new Lookup(), StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()).build();
```

I expect

```
selectionTracker.setOnSelectionEnter
selectionTracker.setOnSelectionExit
```

to toggle buttons "remove selection" "clear selection" visibility

how to do?

update:

I can detect selection status recycler adapter #onBindViewHolder, but it's not good way, when determine onSelectionExit, I must detect all items status each rendering each item

Answer (score 0):

I find solution:

```
  selectionTracker.addObserver(new SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemStateChanged(@NonNull Object key, boolean selected) {
            super.onItemStateChanged(key, selected);
            Selection selection = selectionTracker.getSelection();
            if (selected && selection.size() == 1) {
                if (onSelectionEnter != null) {
                    onSelectionEnter.run();
                }
            } else if (!selected && selection.size() == 0) {
                if (onSelectionExit != null) {
                    onSelectionExit.run();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```